# Optimize this for-loop procedure to avoid a program crash

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization

I'm struggling trying to perform an operation in R without it crashing. I give you a reproducible example. I have X:

```
X <- data.frame(V1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1"),
                Start = c(0, 1001, 3002, 4059, 6581),
                Stop = c(1000, 3001, 4058, 6580, 7002),
                A = c(10, 4, 5, 6, 9),
                B = c(923, 39, 5, 9, 93),
                C = c(239, 2, 13, 4, 5))
```

And I want to perform this operation:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(X)){
  X$A <- (X$A / (X[row, "Stop"] - X[row, "Start"])) * mean(X$Stop - X$Start)
  X$B <- (X$B / (X[row, "Stop"] - X[row, "Start"])) * mean(X$Stop - X$Start)
  X$C <- (X$C / (X[row, "Stop"] - X[row, "Start"])) * mean(X$Stop - X$Start)
}
```

My problem appears when my document is a lot larger (like 2.000.000 rows). Is there any way to do this operation faster in such a large data.frame?

Comment: Try parallel execution with [foreach](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf)

Comment: Why does your PC crash? Out of memory?

Comment: All of your code can be vectorized. 1) `mean(X$Stop - X$Start)` doesn't depend on the loop variable, compute just once. 2) `X$A <- (X$A / (X[, "Stop"] - X[, "Start"]))` times the computed mean.

Comment: Or 2b) `X$A <- X$A / (X$Stop - X$Start) * mean(X$Stop - X$Start)`. And the same for the others.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I don't get the same result if I do it without the loop. That's why I use the loop.

Comment: @Aberod It’s unclear what the code is supposed to do but intuitively I think that Rui’s results are actually the correct ones, and yours are wrong, because you are continuously overwriting the whole column with updated values, which is unlikely to make sense, unless you want to compute something like a cumulative statistic.

Comment: You are totally right @KonradRudolph, many thanks to everyone, I was totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is slow because you are overwriting the entire A, B and C vector each time you go one row. i.e. you are writing over 6.000.000 values for each row (2.000.000 times)

I'd use dplyr here:

```
library(dplyr)

X <- X %>%
 mutate(A = (A/Stop - Start*(Stop-Start)),
        B = (B/Stop - Start*(Stop-Start)),
        C = (C/Stop - Start*(Stop-Start)) )
```

I strongly recommend not overwriting your current ABC values.

```
library(dplyr)

X <- X %>%
 mutate(TRANSFORMED_A = (A/Stop - Start*(Stop-Start)),
        TRANSFORMED_B = (B/Stop - Start*(Stop-Start)),
        TRANSFORMED_C = (C/Stop - Start*(Stop-Start)) )
```

Comment: This is the right approach but I’m not sure that your equations are mathematically equivalent to OP’s.

Comment: To get his original result, he needs to replace "1:nrow(X)" with "nrow(X)"

Answer (score 0):

If you are NOT going to overwrite the whole column with updated values every iteration, you might want to consider these solutions as well. data.table copes pretty well with big datasets.

```
library(data.table)      # loads library
setDT(X)                 # converts data.frame to data.table
cols = c("A", "B", "C")  # defines the columns to update
avg.diff = X[, mean(Stop - Start)]   # caclulates average difference between Stop and Start
X[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {avg.diff * x / (Stop - Start)}), .SDcols = cols]  # makes calculations
```

Or the same, but a bit easier to understand:

```
X[, `:=`(
  A = avg.diff * A / (Stop - Start),
  B = avg.diff * B / (Stop - Start),
  C = avg.diff * C / (Stop - Start)
)]
```

Feel free to adjust these solutions according to your needs.